# I am getting this error when I deploy my contract in ganache using the command node deploy.js

Tags: contract-development, ganache, ganache-cli, etherjs

[image]

I am getting this error when I deploy my contract in ganache using the command node deploy.js

Answer (score 1):

The provider declaration should have been:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers....
```

`new` keyword was missing.